# How to drop a column starting with a Digit in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

Due to some error while uploading data, extra columns got created and one of the column names became 84. Trying to remove that column but getting following error:

```
org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [1100] [HY000]: ERROR:  'ALTER TABLE XXX.XXXXX
DROP 84'
error                                               ^ found "84" (at char 44) expecting an identifier, identifiers must begin with a letter
```

Comment: Use double quotes around the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples of how to handle identifiers that does does not begin with a letter.  You can wrap the identifier in double quotes

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_handle_sql_identifiers.html